# JQuery localStorage.setItem is not storing when using parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store some data in localStorage, but it only seems to store the data on certain URL's.

So for example the below code checks the url for parameters and then stores a certain parameter.

URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_souce=facebook&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=test1
```

JQuery

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
sParameterName,
i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
}
}
};

var campaignName = getUrlParameter('utm_campaign');
if(campaignName != null) {
localStorage.setItem('campaign', campaignName);
}
```

Now if I look at my Local storage on the URL with parameters `(http://www.example.com/?utm_souce=facebook&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=test1)` I can see its saved the data 'campaign' as 'test1'.

But if I go to my URL without the parameters `(http://www.example.com/)` it shows the data 'campaign' as 'undefined'.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: possibly because `campaignName` is not `null` but it is `undefined`...

Comment: try changing `if(campaignName != null) {` to `if(campaignName) {`